# seaborn hue parameter not working correctly

Tags: python, seaborn

I am having trouble getting the seaborn hue to work to color by value. My data is in a pandas df and I am using a barplot.

```
sns.barplot(x = plot_data['gene'], y = plot_data['freq'],
            hue=plot_data["type"],palette={"type1":"red", "type2":"blue"}, ax=ax2)
```

I am confused by the grey bars that appear in places. I expect only red and blue bars and I am sure these are the only two types in the data. 
    [image: output]

Comment: Please check the data and that you aren't useing nested data: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: I don't think my data is nested - each data point is in one row with the "type" column determining the category.

Comment: Can you get this to happen with only three rows of data? And show us the data?

Comment: Impossible to reproduce without sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you draw seaborn barplot in horizontal order because vertically not show proper way that's reason may be you saying [seaborn barplot](https://indianaiproduction.com/seaborn-barplot) hue parameter not working.

and use

```
plt.figure(figsize(9,200)) # for figure size in ration 9:200
```

you can change according to requirement.